# solve $x$ where $ \cos^\pi(x)+\sin^\pi(x)=2^x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> solve
> $x$ where
> $$\cos^\pi(x)+\sin^\pi(x)=2^x$$

we have :
\begin{align*}
\cos^{\pi}(x)+\sin^{\pi}(x)=2^x\\[6pt]
\implies 1+\tan^{\pi}(x)=\frac{2^x}{\cos^\pi(x)}\\[6pt]
\implies \tan^{\pi}(x)=\frac{2^x-\cos^\pi(x)}{\cos^\pi(x)}\\[6pt]
\implies e^{\pi\ln(\tan(x))}=\frac{e^{^x\ln(2)}(1-e^{{-x}\ln(2)+\pi\ln(\cos(x))})}{\cos^\pi(x)}\\[6pt]
\implies e^{\pi\ln(\tan(x))-x\ln(2)}=\frac{(1-e^{-x\ln(2)+\pi\ln(\cos(x))})}{\cos^\pi(x)}\\[6pt]
\implies e^{\pi\ln(\cos(x))+\pi\ln(\tan(x))-x\ln(2)}=(1-e^{-x\ln(2)+\pi\ln(\cos(x))}\\[6pt]
\implies e^{\pi\ln(\sin(x))-x\ln(2)}=(1-e^{-x\ln(2)+\pi\ln(\cos(x))})\\
\end{align*}
But in this case I did not find any idea to deal with this equation
These are the solutions he provided wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=calculate+x+where+%5Ccos%5E%5Cpi%28x%29%2B%5Csin%5E%5Cpi%28x%29%3D2%5Ex)
Any help . I want the solution steps thank's advance

Comment: Why do you think there is a solution that has any nice form?

Comment: @ peter foreman thank's Thanks for the note. I forgot to divide the other side

Comment: Well $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: you are finding integers solutions?

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastian C No, I am looking for solutions in $\mathrm R$ but I need steps on how to get there

Comment: How do you define $y^\pi$ for $y<0$ ? Do you intend complex exponentiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to find the real and complex roots of

$$f(x) = \cos^\pi(x)+\sin^\pi(x)-2^x = 0$$

We can use [*Newton's Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find these roots.

The iteration formula is given by

$$x_{n+1} =x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n-\dfrac{-2^{x_n}+\sin ^{\pi }(x_n)+\cos ^{\pi }(x_n)}{-2^{x_n} \log (2)-\pi  \sin (x_n) \cos ^{\pi -1}(x_n)+\pi  \sin ^{\pi -1}(x_n) \cos (x_n)}$$

With a starting point of $x_0 = -1 + i$, we iterate

- $-1.0000000000000000+ 1.0000000000000000 i$
- $-0.9714119378226440+ 0.6267015393615974 i$
- $-0.8445319842540560+ 0.2240161311167125i$
- $-0.5258268932776222+ 0.0061805753258153i$
- $-0.3907973962837513+ 0.0124923793299834i$
- $-0.3578833077504497+ 0.0206725563410276i$
- $-0.3554879584771613+ 0.022419270719288i$
- $-0.3554840501226612+ 0.0224425445888398i$
- $-0.3554840515953923+ 0.0224425448695188i$

Compare that to the Wolfram Alpha result.

A second root is the complex conjugate or choose $x_0 = -1 - i$ and repeat the process.

As mentioned in the comments, the only real root is $x = 0$.